# Does each ROM has its own boot?

Tags: partitions, kernel

At the moment, I have Redmi Note 7 on Pixel Experience. I do not like the kernel it has. As a result, I tried to change it by flashing the `boot.img` of the stock ROM. Unfortunately, it remains stuck at the splash scren.

I also formatted the `/Data` partition, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: basically , yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each ROM has its own boot unless the ROM is explicitly build keeping the stock kernel. SO to able to boot your device again, unzip your PixelExperience ROM file, take boot.img from it and flash that.